# Are free messaging Apps genuine?

Tags: applications

There are lot of free messaging Apps in the App store.

I would like to know whether the following two apps are genuine : [way2sms](http://www.way2sms.com) and [Kik](http://kik.com/)

And I was just wondering, how are they able develop such apps and allow people to use it for free ?

Comment: In most cases, you don't use apps for free. You might not be paying money – but you pay with your personal data for advertizements etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such apps are genuine.

I am not familiar with Kik, but assuming it is similar to way2sms, they gain advertising revenue from page views.

Kik mentions having over 120 million users and way2sms has 40 million+ users.

For example for the 40 million users of way2sms, assuming that the advertising rate is $0.01 per 1000 page views (I'm not sure about the actual rates). And assuming an average of 10 page views per user per week. Which gives 400 million page views a week.

Then the advertising earnings will be $4000 per week. (The above is just an example, I'm sure I made a lot of wrong assumptions)

> So the way2sms business model is to buy messages from network
>   operators and give these messages free to the users, and recoup the
>   cost from advertising revenue gained from page views.

I'm assuming kik does somethig similar.

A brief interview with the founder of way2sms can be found [here](http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/raju-vanapala-the-man-behind-way2smscoms-success_587304.html).
And another article [here](http://dhannyya.hubpages.com/hub/Few-interesting-facts-about-Way2sms-the-power-house-of-messaging).

Edit : I did some reading up on Kik, I didn't find much but I think they use a freemium model where their app and basic services are free but they charge for some additional services.

For example, they charge money for some stickers.